# error while configuring Qt 4.6.2 on ubuntu - "You don't seem to have 'make' or 'gmake' in your PATH. cannot proceed"

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt4

I am trying to install Qt 4.6.2 on ubuntu. When I run the configure script I get the following error message "You don't seem to have 'make' or 'gmake' in your PATH. cannot proceed".

On echo of the PATH variable I get

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

on running the command

> $which make , I get
>
> /usr/bin/make

How do I proceed with this issue? I seem to have the make in the path env variable but still the config script throws cannot find make or gmake?

Comment: I don't presume it would be something so simple as closing your term and reopening it to make sure your environment is up to date after apt-get?

Comment: What does `config.tests/unix/which.test make` return ? Looking at configure source, it seems you could `export MAKE=/usr/bin/make` but that won't tell you why it doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: In my case when installing from Ubuntu the scripts in config.tests/unix have their execute bit munged by unzip as @mr-shickadance pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the source again. I am able to run configure without any problems. Seems like there was an issue with the earlier source.

Comment: I also had the same issues, but re-extracting the archive didn't help. What I found was that mny of the executable programs in the archive did not have the execute bit set, so a simple `chmod` fixed the issue. It seems like the unix `unzip` utility munges the file permissions when it extracts.

Answer (score 7):

It not the problem of make or gmake, nor PATH, Just because you unzip the tarball without -a option. so, to solve this problem, just use 'unzip -a *.zip', it will be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm! Can you explain why the -a option makes the difference though?

Answer (score 7):

I recently encountered this error in a `fedora32` docker container, because the `which` utility was not installed. I was compiling Qt 5.12.9.

`dnf install which` fixed the problem.

Comment: Just encountered the same thing on an AWS Amazon Linux container

Answer (score 3):

You should have been installed build-essentials but did not restart try either to restart or type:

```
export MAKE=/usr/bin/make
```

and make sure with `echo $MAKE`

Comment: had same problem on OSX - export MAKE  solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should install build essentials

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and type`sudo apt make install`